# Rails: Active storage has_many association callback for each upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have this model in which I am using has many active storage association

```
class Cloud < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
  has_many_attached :videos

  validates :images, content_type: { in: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'images/gif'] , message: 'should be of type png, jpg, jpeg and gif.'}
  validates :videos, content_type: { in: ['video/mp4', 'video/x-flv', 'video/x-msvideo', 'video/x-ms-wmv', 'video/avi', 'video/quicktime'], message: 'should be of type mp4, x-flv, x-msvideo, x-ms-wmv, avi and quicktime(mov).' }
  validates :videos, size: { greater_than: 1.kilobytes , message: 'size is invalid' }
  validates :images, size: { greater_than: 1.kilobytes , message: 'size is invalid' }
end
```

Now I need to add callback that everytime when any video is added into if there content type is not `video/mp4` then I will convert it with ffmpeg in sidekiq I need to run worker to do this job

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this (it will work 1st time):

```
after_save :check_video_format

def check_video_format
  if videos.attached?
    videos.each do |video|
      if video.persisted? && video.content_type != 'video/mp4'
        # do your job here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can create initializer to monkeypatch `ActiveStorage` like this:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/module/delegation"

class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :fix_video_format, if: -> { record_type == 'Cloud' && name == 'videos' }

  def fix_video_format
    if content_type != 'video/mp4'
      # do your job here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this will work if I have uploaded 3 videos at first time then after some time if I upload fourth video? I know there is check of `content_type ` but wanted to learn if this could work with out `content_type ` validation . Suppose if I wanted to do some stuff on every new video upload, how can I get that hook

Comment: @VishalG you can monkey patch `ActiveStorage`

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/attached/many.rb#L30 

yes I was thinking the same it is the only way to do that